# DtPicker control value not updated after user selects date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class that adds 3-4 dtPickers to a userform dynamically at runtime. The dtPickers are added to the userform as I anticipate, and I'm able to choose different dates for each one.

My problem is that I have been unable to "record" the new date that the user chooses back to the spreadsheet. The value being sent back is 0. Is there a specific way I should be handling the events for this control or adjusting its value at runtime?

Additional info: I store the class that creates the dtPicker in a collection and then create the class during initialization. I tried to add events to the class but haven't been able to successfully trigger them.

Please let me know if you need any additional info, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out my mistake. When I declared the dtPicker in my class I neglected to declare it WithEvents (Private WithEvents date1 as DTPicker).